# Display image using C#

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic

I'm using mvc2 and I would like to use action in controller, for example `ShowSmallImage)` and when I type www.url.com/ShowSmallImage that in browser the output is an image.

I tried something like this:

```
public Bitmap CreateThumbnail()
        {
            Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:...\Uploads\Photos\178.jpg");

            int newWidth = 100;
            int newHeight = 100;
            double ratio = 0;

            if (img1.Width > img1.Height)
            {
                ratio = img1.Width / (double)img1.Height;
                newHeight = (int)(newHeight / ratio);
            }
            else
            {
                ratio = img1.Height / (double)img1.Width;
                newWidth = (int)(newWidth / ratio);
            }

            //a holder for the result 
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

            //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap 
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                //set the resize quality modes to high quality 
                graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                //draw the image into the target bitmap 
                graphics.DrawImage(img1, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

As a result I get only System.Drawing.Bitmap in browser. I suppose I need to set response/content type of the page but have no idea how to do it...

Thanks,
Ile

Comment: Where are you actually writing this out to the response stream? All you're doing here is image manipulation.

Comment: In the controller. I want to do manipulation first and then display thumbnail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a fileresult and return the stream to the bitmap & set the content type:

```
    private FileResult RenderImage()
    {   
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var bitmap = CreateThumbnail();
        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        Byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
        return File(bytes, "image/png");

    }
```

Comment: hmm... with this I get only blank page

Comment: Are you sure you CreateThumbnail() method is working correctly?

Comment: got it... in the last line it's suppose to be bytes instead of stream: return File(bytes, "image/png"); Now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ha. Thats what I get for not using intellisense. ;-) I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

In a controller, say `ResourceController` you could have an `Action` that returns a `FileResult`. Like so

```
    public FileResult Thumbnail()
    {
        var bitmap = // Your method call which returns a Bitmap

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/png");
    }
```

Then you can call `http://www.mysite.com/Resource/Thumbnail`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how how to build byteArray. Can I use this current function I have in this action you created? Thx